# how can I keep my game character in canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, web-applications, keyboard

I'm working on a 'frogger-like'game and have the following code for moving my character around a canvas element.  The code works, however the character is able to 'step out/leave' the canvas.  I've tried putting `handleInput()` in the `update(dt)` (update checks for updates)nested in a if statement (`if player.x is > don't do this....`)but I get a syntax error.  A ternary statement in the `switch` works - however, that's how they did it in a tutorial I followed and I'm trying really hard not to just 'copy' the tutorial.  Any advice is much appreciated!

```
window.allowedKeys = {
    37: 'left',
    38: 'up',
    39: 'right',
    40: 'down'
};

const allowedKeys = window.allowedKeys;

 update(dt){

    }

    handleInput(input){

        switch(input) {
            case 'left':
             allowedKeys['left'] = this.x -= 1;
                break;
            case 'up':
            allowedKeys['up'] = this.y -= 1;
                break;
            case 'right':
            allowedKeys['right'] = this.x += 1;
                break;
            case 'down':
            allowedKeys['down'] = this.y += 1;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {

    player.handleInput(allowedKeys[e.keyCode]);

});
```

Comment: Is handleInput a function?  Where is the `function` keyword (or arrow notation)?

Comment: Totally forgot to add that! sorry....
`document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    player.handleInput(allowedKeys[e.keyCode]);
});`

Comment: Update your question don't just add you missing code in the comments.... and preferably create a code snippet

Comment: This code is still incomplete, now it looks like handleInput is supposed to be a method of a "player" object.  Where is that.

Answer (score 0):

adding this to update() fixed the issue :) with the fun extra benefit of left/right screen scrolling!

```
update(dt){
       if(player.x > 5){
           player.x = 0;
       }
       if(player.x < 0){
        player.x = 5;
    }
        if(player.y > 4.5){
            player.y -= 1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think that you want to validate what is the key that the user, press here is an example, I use prototype but i believe that you're using es6 class. You don't need to declare the global var allowedKeys neither update it. I hope that help you

```js
// movements with javascript
const allowedKeys = {
    37: 'left',
    38: 'up',
    39: 'right',
    40: 'down'
};

function Player(target)  {
  this.x = 0
  this.y = 0
  this.target = target
}

Player.prototype.handleInput = function(input){
        switch(input) {
            case 'left':
               this.x -= 1;
                break;
            case 'up':
              this.y -= 1;
                break;
            case 'right':
              this.x += 1;
                break;
            case 'down':
              this.y += 1;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }


Player.prototype.update = function (dt){

}

const player = new Player("player1")

document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    player.handleInput(allowedKeys[e.keyCode]);
    const element = document.getElementById(player.target)
    element.innerHTML = "x:" + player.x + "  y:" + player.y
});
```

```html
<div id="player1"> Press an Arrow </div>
```